# Leaflet.Snap snapping is not working with leaflet-draw 1.0.0

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

**leaflet-draw**

```
  "name": "leaflet-draw",
  "description": "Vector drawing plugin for Leaflet",
  "version": "1.0.2",
```

**leaflet-snap**

```
"name": "leaflet-snap",
"version": "0.0.3",
"description": "Enable snapping between layers",
```

**leaflet-draw-toolbar**

```
  "version": "0.3.0-alpha.1"
```

When run with this configuration snap editing is not working - i mean the points to which it's supposed to snap are not showing up and "sticking" not happens. But if i add the leaflet-draw dependency from the same package as a leaflet-snap (`L.drawVersion = '0.3.0-dev';`
) then sticking is working fine, but i lose the ability to edit features, as when the dragging points are shown but moving them doesn't change the position of them. So i think there is a version compatibility issue and I tried a lot of version combinations to make everything work, without success. In my opinion Leaflet.Snap requires some older version of Leaflet.Draw while leaflet-draw-toolbar requires a higher one.